# SQL no duplicate data

Tags: sql, postgresql

i want to remove the duplicate parts but the DISTINCT function isnt working

INPUT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT artist, streams
FROM spotify_daily_charts a
ORDER BY a.streams DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

OUPUT:

```
artist           streams

BTS               753286
BTS               684292
BLACKPINK         670517
Adele             641241
BTS               621135
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifer_, and here gives you distinct _rows_.

Comment: What other result would you expect?

Comment: What did you expect - one BTS row? If so, check out GROUP BY and SUM().

Comment: You are getting the top 5 streams with their artists. This is what you tell the DBMS to give you, and this is what you get. You also say that there may be duplicate stream/artist pairs and you want such duplicates to get removed (by applying `DISTINCT` on your result). Your result does hence not contain any duplicates. If it is something else you want, then tell the DBMS what it is you want.

Comment: There are no duplicates in your output. DISTINCT works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The Distinct operator is applied on **both** `artist` and `streams` fields.
If you want a DISTINCT `artist` you need to add some operator on the `streams` field **and** a GROUP BY on `artist` and to remove the DISTINCT, something like this -

```
SELECT artist, MAX(streams)
FROM spotify_daily_charts a
GROUP BY artist
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```